# Transfer data to a sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Consume_RoundedRectangle111_Click()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, n As Long
Dim vResult()
Dim myWs As Worksheet

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Range("B9").Text)

If ActiveSheet.Range("b4") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("b5") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("b6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("b7") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("b8") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("b9") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("d4") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("d6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("d7") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("d8") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all fields!"
Exit Sub
End If

'lastrow = Sheets("database").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = 10
Do While Cells(i, 3) <> "" And i < 30
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To 9, 1 To n)
    vResult(1, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("E7") ' Consumer
    vResult(2, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("B4") ' Date
    vResult(3, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("E4") ' Ref
    vResult(4, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("B5") ' Code
    vResult(5, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("B6") ' Description
    vResult(6, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("E6") ' U/M
    vResult(7, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("B7") ' Qty
    vResult(8, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("B8") ' Price
    vResult(9, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("E8") ' Transaction
    i = i + 1

Loop

myWs.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(n, 9) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)

MsgBox "Saved Succesfully!"
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

This is the code that I know, it copies the data from one sheet to another sheet called database. But what I want right now is to transfer or copy a data to a sheet determined by a cell. Let's say I have a data to be copied in another sheet and in cell A5 it contains "NBB", when I run the macro, the data will be copied to the sheet named "NBB". Sorry for for that, I am just having a hard time explaining this on english...

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: Can you please give more details around your question?  Your title is very disingenuous, and it should be more descriptive.  Same with your question. You haven't exactly asked what you are trying to accomplish.  Please read [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to properly ask questions that have a better change of receiving a positive and helpful answer. Without any detailed information about your issue, no one here can truly assist you

Comment: I've edited it, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @braX  I have updated the code above, and with that I am having a error "Invalid procedure call or argument" in the line just after the "Loop"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I dont think you can do this: `End(xlUp)(2)` - remove the `(2)` and see if that makes the error go away, even if it doesnt do what you want, then figure out a way to do what you want the correct way.

Comment: the same error =(

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are asking for more than I am about to provide, so if this does not completely answer what you need, please comment below and I will update my answer.

If cell `A5` has the sheetname you want to navigate to, then copying data to that sheet is easy enough.  Just do something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20").Copy Destination:=Worksheets(Range("A5").Text).Range("A1:A20")
```

This will take your ActiveSheet you are working on, take Range `A1:A20`, copy and paste them to Range `A1:A20` on the sheetname pulled from `Range("A5").Text`.  I expect some of this will need to be edited to pull the data you want (which range you want to pull the data from) and paste it to the range you want.

For additional information, please check out [MSDN Range.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel), as it may contain tips or useful information when working with `Range.Copy`.  This also shows how the `Destination` paramteter works, which is what I used to show which Sheet and Range you would be pasting the data to.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: sadly that won't work, I have updated the code above, and with that I am having a error "Invalid procedure call or argument" in the line just after the "Loop"